# using query strings in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, http-get

In Laravel, building a route takes the form:

```
Route::get('testing', function(){
    return 0 //whatever
});
```

If I want to include a query string, so that I could navigate to `localhost/testing?p1=blah&p2=blah2...`, is there a built in way to do this?  The only thing I can think of is to use a single variable and parse the string myself:

```
Route::get('testing\\?{query}, function($query){ //I'm not sure if you have to escape the questionmark
    //parse the string manually
    return 0 //whatever
});
```

I feel like there must be a built in way to do this a little better, but I can't figure out what it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Query strings are not part of the route. You can get to them with `request($key)`:

```php
Route::get('testing', function(){
    return request('p1');
});
```

You can also get an associative array with everything in the query string, by calling the `all` method:

```php
Route::get('testing', function(){
    return request()->all();
});
```

> **Note**: if you're using an older version of Laravel, use `Input::get()` & `Input::all()`, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do `request()->all()` or `request()->get('p1')`